# Not Able To Destroy CKEditor Instance

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

**Before I updated CKEditor** to Latest Stable Release **4.5.6** everything was **working perfectly** but after I updated I got this **error** while try to **destroy** the ckeditor instance using below codes

```
//this is what i was using originally
    CKEDITOR.instances.textarea1.destroy() 

//this is what i found on the internet but gave the same error
    CKEDITOR.instances.textarea1.destroy(false) 
    CKEDITOR.instances.textarea1.destroy(true)
    CKEDITOR.instances[textarea1].destroy()
    CKEDITOR.instances[textarea1].destroy(false)
    CKEDITOR.instances[textarea1].destroy(true)
```

Error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getClientRect' of null

[image: Ckeditor Error]

I am using this editor in a sharepoint 2013 project

Help is always appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: could you put here the full error's stack trace?

Comment: @thiagoh this is the line in ckeditor.js where I am getting this error
'g=c.getClientRect(),m=a.getClientRect(),l,f=this._notificationWidth'

Comment: please add the stacktrace to your question so we can read it fully @maitiest

Comment: @thiagoh Updated. Thanks